# Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 1)

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a model to classify(binary) my picture,but I got this problem,could anyone help me to solve it.Thank you guys~
here is the model, and the training process

```js
def googLeNet(input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))):
    .................
    .................
    ...............
    averagepool1_7x7_s1 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7), padding='same')(inception_5b)
    drop1 = Dropout(rate=0.4)(averagepool1_7x7_s1)
    linear = Dense(units=1, activation='linear')(drop1)
    last = Dense(units=1, activation='softmax')(linear)
    model = Model(input=input, outputs=last)
    return model

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=20,
    class_mode='binary'
)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=20,
    class_mode='binary'
)

model = googLeNet()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc']
              )

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=100,
                              epochs=30,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              validation_steps=50
                              )
```

Comment: try `train_generator = np.squeeze(train_generator)`